# How to upgrade drush version in linux mint?

Tags: drupal-8, drush

In 
**NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.1 (Serena)"**

> sudo apt-get install drush

to install the drush in my system.

when I use

> drush version

I still getting version 5.10.0

Even I tried composer also

> composer global require drush/drush
>   composer require drush/drush

Now I am still getting drush version 5.10.0. how do I make it use drush updated version?

WHen I run

> drupal dl

for download latest version of drupal 8.5.6. But I am getting drush downloading drupal-7.59

I am new to drush & drupal. Please help me to fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can get lateset version of drush from "https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/".
In there You can get out latest version number of drush from release page.

wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/< Version goes here>/drush.phar

```
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.17/drush.phar
chmod +x drush.phar
sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush
drush --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path settings are likely still pointing towards the outdated install as you now have two versions of drush installed.

Run "which drush" to see where its pointed and fix it to composer location.

Comment: Via composer based installation I missed that step Add composer's bin directory to the system path by placing export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" into your ~/.bash_profile (Mac OS users) or into your ~/.bashrc (Linux users).